# how to save multiple Django forms with foreign keys?

Tags: python, django

I know this question has been asked before and I applied the suggested solutions but still, my code is not working. I am trying to save 3 forms which one of the models has foreign keys of the other two. I try `commit=false` at first and then save but I still get the `IntegrityError`. Here are details of the traceback:

> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
>     85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>
> The above exception (null value in column "poi_id" violates not-null constraint
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (14, SOME STRING, 2019-05-01, media/Live-Oak-Tree-450w_iWBYljS.jpg, null, null).
>   ) was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
>     126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
>     124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "C:\testBioDjango\SpeciesColl\polls\views.py" in observe
>     52.                 obs.species = species_form.save()
>
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in save
>     458.             self.instance.save()
>
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
>     718.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
>     748.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
>     831.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
>     869.                                using=using, raw=raw)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
>     82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
>     1136.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
>     1289.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
>     100.             return super().execute(sql, params)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
>     68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
>     77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
>     85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in **exit**
>     89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
>
> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
>     85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>
> Exception Type: IntegrityError at /polls/observe/
>   Exception Value: null value in column "poi_id" violates not-null constraint
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (14, SOME STRING, 2019-05-01, media/Live-Oak-Tree-450w_iWBYljS.jpg, null, null).

Comment: What integrity error? Show the whole thing.

Comment: No, the *whole* thing. Update your question with the full traceback.

Comment: That's still not the traceback. We need to see the exact line this error happens on, I am doubtful it is coming from this code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for your comment. added the full traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're swapping the names of the forms when you assign them:

```
species_form = ObservationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

that's where things go wrong.

How you could have seen it yourself: As Daniel pointed out, the error trace showed the error was happening on `species_form.save()` (look for lines in your error trace that have a path to your own code, rather than a path to python/site-packages/django/...). But further down the trace, you can see values for the failing row: `(14, SOME STRING, 2019-05-01, media/Live-Oak-Tree-450w_iWBYljS.jpg, null, null)` which obviously refers to the `Observation` model. So `species_form` saves the wrong model.

Comment: ahhh yes that's right. thanks a lot. I fixed it and it works now. thanks